# How to avoid "unsaved form changes" after submit response is an attachment?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, http-post

Never mind the following.  I discovered that my problem was caused by js code elsewhere in the app.

My application does a form submit. This goes to a action method on a controller, which does this:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SQLQueryResult.csv");
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", sb.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.End();
return null;
```

This works nicely. The browser treats this as a attachment to download.  However, the browser also presents the "unsaved form changes" prompt.

Is there any way to avoid this prompt?  I didn't have this problem when it was a plain asp.net page, but now that I've converted to mvc I do.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say but the code you have shown is an anti-MVC pattern. Here's how an MVC controller action serving a file to download would look like:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    StringBuilder sb = ...
    var csv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    return File(csv, "text/csv", "SQLQueryResult.csv");
}
```

As you can see controller actions do not write to the response. That's not their purpose. They return action results. It is those action results that should take care of presenting the results to the client.

Comment: That's a good tip. I've changed my code and now it's prettier but I still have the problem.

Comment: I discovered that my problem was caused by js code elsewhere in the app.